# Security Issue if Javascript evaluated by Java on the Server

Tags: java, javascript, security, rhino

If I evaluate a Javascript code submitted from the browser,  on the server (Java webapp using Rhino Javascript Engine),  does it pose security risk?

The Evaulation of the Javascript is being done only to know if its a valid Javascript.

I don't expect the evaluation to return me anything. I don't expect it store anything, or touch anything. All it should do is tell me is the user submitted valid javascript.

If it is something that poses security issues, can I take some steps to make sure that the JavaScript will not cause any harm to the system?

Comment: Valid JavaScript can be used to harm systems; it is up to you to define what is harmful and what is not. I think you need to re-think your security model here. Posting more information about what you intend to protect or what you intend to prevent will help.

Comment: If you just want to make sure that the enteredd javascript is valid, then you only need to compile it right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it poses a security risk, because from JavaScript inside Rhino it's possible to access anything in the Java runtime, including (for example) all the `java.io` classes.

You can make sure that all your calls to Rhino operate under the jurisdiction of a SecurityManager that restricts basically everything. With the JDK's ScriptEngine code there's no built-in way to do that; I don't know about what tools are available for Rhino as used with the Mozilla hooks.

Comment: The JDK version of Rhino should restrict what the script can do to the permissions available when the script was started. However, it will by default have access to your application code, which generally wont be secure.

Comment: Right, that's what I mean - it's pretty common for something like a web server to be running without a restrictive security manager, and even if there is one, it's probably more permissive than what you'd like to hand over to any random script posted to a public URL :-)